# How to Divide the Sum of a Range by each Row from the Range in Google Sheets with Query?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Query to pull Columns A and B from another sheet like this:

```
Query(Tank_List!A1:M716, "select A,E, SUM (E) Where B=1 Group by A,E",1)
```

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 9240 | 9240 |
| Item 2 | 11843 | 11843 |
| Item 3 | 6372 | 6372 |
| Item 4 | 8320 | 8320 |
| Item 5 | 16365 | 16365 |
| Item 6 | 1234 | 1234 |

Instead of returning the actual Sum of ColB (The SUM of the Range of numbers from ColB) it returns just a copy of ColB on it's line.

I've tried several ways but the issue is SUM returns a single total for ColB or as above, the SUM of just the Row.

I am hoping for something like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 9240 | 53374 | ColC/ColB |
| Item 2 | 11843 | 53374 | ColC/ColB |
| Item 3 | 6372 | 53374 | ColC/ColB |
| Item 4 | 8320 | 53374 | ColC/ColB |
| Item 5 | 16365 | 53374 | ColC/ColB |
| Item 6 | 1234 | 53374 | ColC/ColB |

Where I can do equations based on the original range numbers and the total SUM of that range. I imagine the answer will have to do with ArrayFormula, but I could not make it work myself.

Comment: Provide input data sample for the  given output and expected output.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want as you have columns not listed, but it would probably be easist to just grab the number using a regular sum value, then parse it into your query.  I didn't duplicate your sheet, but used the below sample data and this formula:

```
=Query(A:B, "Select A, Sum(B), "&sum(B:B)&",SUM (B)/"&sum(B:B)&" where A is not null Group by A",1)
```

You can see the output pasted in cell `E1` which has the division done in column `G`.

[image]

**Your Sample Data**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 9240 |
| Item 2 | 11843 |
| Item 3 | 6372 |
| Item 4 | 8320 |
| Item 5 | 16365 |
| Item 6 | 1234 |

Comment: Small correction... the screenshot doesn't include your total column (3), but I included it in formula.

Comment: This looks close enough to get me on the path. Thanks so much.

Comment: pg, could you help me to understand why this works on the same sheet, but if I query it to another sheet it does not work? It seems to be that the formula will not accept "&sum(Col5:Col5)&". It reduces it to "&sum(Col5)&". Also, the Sum(B) sums a part of, or all of B not just the rows I call using "Where" clauses. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ProfDingledong post sample data or strip your question down to the absolute minimal amount of information that explains the expectation and what's not happening. Too hard to understand written descriptions as I don't know what the difference of `Sum(Col5:Col5)` and `Sum(Col5)` or why that matters.

Comment: I I use this code: ```=Query(Tank_List!A1:M, "Select A,Sum(E),"&sum(E:E)&",SUM(E)/"&sum(E:E)&" where B= 1 Group by A Order by SUM(E)/"&sum(E:E)&" desc label "&sum(E:E)&" 'Total Battles', SUM(E)/"&sum(E:E)&" 'Odds' format SUM(E)/"&sum(E:E)&" '0.00%'",1)```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FILTER` instead `QUERY`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({FILTER({Tank_List!A1:A,Tank_List!E1:E},Tank_List!B1:B=1),FILTER(Tank_List!E1:E,Tank_List!B1:B=1)/SUMIF(Tank_List!B1:B,1,Tank_List!E1:E)})
```

Retrieve columns ***A*** and ***E*** in the first part of array, then for each value in ***E*** that I divide for a sum with `SUMIF`.